# In python, how would I create a dictionary of all unique words listed in a text file. So far I have this code. Thanks

Tags: python, dictionary, nltk

```
def getUniqueWords(wordsList) :
    """
    Returns the subset of unique words containing all of the words that are presented in the
    text file and will only contain each word once. This function is case sensitive
    """
    uniqueWords = {}
    for word in speech :
        if word not in speech:
            uniqueWords[word] = []
    uniqueWords[word].append(word)
```

Comment: I think you meant `if word not in uniqueWords:`

Comment: The last line needs to be indented inside the `for` loop.

Comment: What is `speech`? Should that be `wordsList`?

Comment: You need to `return uniqueWords` at the end.

Comment: speech was what I used when I cleaned up and segmented the text file from another function earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are passing a clean list of words to `getUniqueWords()`, you can always return a `set` of the list which will, because of the properties of a set, remove duplicates.

Try:

```py
def getUniqueWords(wordsList):
  return set(wordsList)
```

Note: When you type questions, you are using `markdown`, enclosing your code in back ticks it makes the formatting nice with the grey box.  Single tick makes the box inline `like this` and three back ticks with the language at the top gives the box.

Edit: *To help with your comment*

You can do what calling `set()` on a list does, but manually:

```py
wordList = ['b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'f']

def getUniqueWords(wordList):
    unique = set()
    for word in wordList:
        unique.add(word)
    return unique

print(getUniqueWords(wordList))
```

This is what calling `set()` on a `list` does.  Also, using no built in functions on an open ended question (without specifying a method) is a silly addition to any question, *especially* when your using python.

Comment: Thank you so much, would there be a way to accomplish this without using a built-in function?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see why you would want too, as if you already have a `list` of words, the best way would be to manually add them to a `set` since you can generate a unique word list in linear time as opposed to going through each word and then traversing each entry in a list keeping track of unique entries to see if it already exists.

Comment: I agree that it would be more efficient to do it that way but the question I was assigned states we are not allowed to use any built-in functions.

Comment: Also, a `set` works like a `dict` type (hashing) but does not map a `key` to a `value`, rather just stores a `key`

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

```
text = 'a, a, b, b, b, a'

u = set(text.split(', '))

# u={'a', 'b'}
```